# How to apply minmax scaler according to different dataframe

Tags: python

i have a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({

'category': ['fruits','fruits','fruits','fruits','fruits','vegetables','vegetables','vegetables','vegetables','vegetables'],
'product' : ['apple','orange','durian','coconut','grape','cabbage','carrot','spinach','grass','potato'],
'sales'   : [10,20,30,40,100,10,30,50,60,100]

})

df.head(15)
```

current method: normalize according to a single category in df, manually

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df_fruits = df[df['category'] == "fruits"]
df_fruits['sales'] = scaler.fit_transform(df_fruits[['sales']])
df_fruits.head()
df_fruits = pd.to_csv('minmax/output/category-{}-minmax.csv'.format('XX'))
```

questions: 
- how to loop through accordingly to all the category in df 
- then how to export the csv file accordingly with category name in it

thanks a lot

Comment: did you try using `groupby`

for instance `df.groupby('category')['sales'].agg(scaler.fit_transform)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.unique`:

```
for i in df["category"].unique():
    cat = df[df['category'] == i]
    cat['sales'] = scaler.fit_transform(cat[['sales']])
    cat.to_csv('minmax/output/category-{}-minmax.csv'.format(i))
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_csv' , which part i did wrong?

Comment: Sorry, a simple typo. Edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to perform some function gymnastics for this to work.

Your `dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({

'category': ['fruits','fruits','fruits','fruits','fruits','vegetables','vegetables','vegetables','vegetables','vegetables'],
'product' : ['apple','orange','durian','coconut','grape','cabbage','carrot','spinach','grass','potato'],
'sales'   : [10,20,30,40,100,10,30,50,60,100]

})
```

```
def minmax_wrapper(x):
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    return pd.Series(scaler.fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1)).flatten())
```

Now apply it to your grouped dataframe.

```
df['scaled_sales'] = df.groupby('category')['sales'].transform(minmax_wrapper)
```

Voila!

You can iterate through your groups using

```
# I believe this should work haven't tried it out
for category, grouped in df.groupby('category'):
    grouped.to_csv(f"minmax/output/category-{category}-minmax.csv")
```